# Looking for a tv show about survivors in an island and an eye patch man in a submarine

Tags: story-identification, tv

It's not Lost, but I heard that this TV show is an inspiration to Lost.

I'm looking for a TV series from probably the 90s or early. It's about survivors of a shipwreck or something similar that got lost in an island. As the episodes go, some of the characters die or get killed.

I remember of a particularly character that wears an eyepatch, like a pirate, and stays at a submarine. He had something to do with the mysteries of the island and the survivors.

Those mysteries through the series vary from science fiction and fantasy elements to drama elements, but I can not really describe them, because, well, I don't remember.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you describe any actually science fictional or fantastical elements in the show? Otherwise it is, unfortunately, not on-topic on this site.

Comment: As I've a described in the question, there is handful of mysteries revolving the island and the man in the submarine. This mysteries through the series vary from science fiction and fantasy elements to drama elements. I can add this comment to the main question if helps clarify.

Comment: That does help clarify, although still sceptical we keep questions open and give them the benefit of the doubt. Remember to keep adding any details that come back to you and updating your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be the 1995 TV version of "Mysterious Island", a loose interpretation of the J. Verne novel? There were several other movie versions of this story as well and the character you describe seems very "Nemo-esque". There are some youtube videos of this show.

Comment: What about the TV version makes it similar to the story described, can you provide some details linking the two?

Comment: It's "Mysterious Island". There have been like a thousand remakes of the story. Castaways crash land on an unknown island, usually in a balloon. Usually they are civil war soldiers. Often they have to battle strange creatures. Captain Nemo lurks about in his submarine manipulating events. If it is indeed "Mysterious Island" the poster is referring to, I think that Jules Verne pretty solidly falls in to the Sci-FI category. No?

Comment: Yep! It's the 1995 canadian tv version! The shipwreck is actually a balloon crash and the man in the submarine is indeed captain Nemo. Here is the source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysterious_Island_(TV_series). Many thanks!